# Receiving TLS 1.0 and 1.1 from server despite disabling it in the registry and disabling FIPS compliant algorithms

Tags: ssl, iis, cloudflare

Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10.

Used these scripts to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1

> New-Item `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server'`
> -Force `
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server'`
> -name 'Enabled' `-value '0'`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server'`
> -name 'DisabledByDefault' `-value 1`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> New-Item `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client'`
> -Force `
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client'`
> -name 'Enabled' `-value '0'`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client'`
> -name 'DisabledByDefault' `-value 1`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> Write-Host 'TLS 1.0 has been disabled.'

> New-Item `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server'`
> -Force `
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server'`
> -name 'Enabled' `-value '0'`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server'`
> -name 'DisabledByDefault' `-value 1`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> New-Item `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client'`
> -Force `
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client'`
> -name 'Enabled' `-value '0'`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client'`
> -name 'DisabledByDefault' `-value 1`
> -PropertyType 'DWord' `-Force`
> | Out-Null
>
> Write-Host 'TLS 1.0 has been disabled.'

Ran "IISCRYPTO" and result:

[image]

Tested with this OPENSSL:

[image]

Qualys Dallas website shows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to reboot your server for your changes to effect the system.

Comment: You don't need to include the script. It would help for you to include the output of your check of the registry values.

Comment: Recent versions of OpenSSL can be and yours apparently is configured to disable TLS1.0 and sometimes 1.1; **your test** with `openssl s_client -tls1` giving error 0A0000BF is a local error and didn't actually attempt a 1.0 connection at all, so it **doesn't prove anything** about the server. For testing only (NEVER in prod) try adding `-cipher DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0`. (PS: the Qualys site is not 'Dallas'?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the domain name you've tried to mask can still be extracted from the part of the certificate you show. From knowing the domain name it is possible to get the details you did not provide in your question.

Your IIS server is behind a CDN (ArvanCloud). The TLS is terminated at the CDN. This means that from the perspective of an external client (like SSLLabs) only the CDN settings are relevant, not the settings of your IIS server behind the CDN.

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me when disabling 1.0 and 1.1, setting 1.2 as default.

With a couple changes it may help you too.

Step 1: Enable TLS 1.2

From Notepad.exe, create a text file and name it TLS12-Enable.reg.

Copy then paste the following text:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
```

Save the TLS12-Enable.reg file.

Double-click the TLS12-Enable.reg file.

Click Yes to update your Windows Registry with these changes.

Step 2: Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1

From Notepad.exe, create a text file and name it TLS1011-Disable.reg

Copy then paste the following text:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Save the TLS1011-Disable.reg file.

Double-click the TLS1011-Disable.reg file.

Click Yes to update your Windows Registry with these changes.

Step 3: Configure .NET Security Settings

From Notepad.exe, create a text file and name it NET-UseSchannelDefaults.reg

Copy then paste the following text:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
```

Save the NET-UseSchannelDefaults.reg file.

Double-click the NET-UseSchannelDefaults.reg file.

Click Yes to update your Windows Registry with these changes.

Restart your computer for the change to take effect.